# Reusing PARDISO symbolic factorization

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays, interoperability

Is there a way to do this natively in Mathematica? I read in several places that this is possible with LibraryLink, but I don't have a lot of experience with C and so I'm having trouble implementing this approach.

---

I came across the documentation for [Affine Covariant Newton Method](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationMethodsForSolvingNonlinearEquations.html#45025331) where it states

> When an iterative method like `"Krylov"` is specified as a method to `LinearSolve`, then the factorization of the Jacobian is not stored when possible, but computed anew every time it is needed.

which seems to indicate that it stores the factorization when using a direct method.

Comment: I'll only note that if you try to inspect the result of something like `LinearSolve[mat, Method -> "Pardiso"]` or `LinearSolve[m, Method -> "Krylov"]`, the input matrix `mat` is stored along with a ``SparseArray`SparseLUDecomposition[]`` header in the former, and just the matrix itself in the latter, but with flags indicating which sparse method was used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, this is not built-in and I have been waiting quite long for such a feature.

## PardisoLink

With the help of Szabolcs's package ["LTemplate`"](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate) I had written such an interface for the Intel MKL Pardiso that is shipped with *Mathematica* a couple of years ago. I spent all day to bring it into a shape that has at least a small chance to run on a computer different from mine. You can find it on [**github**](https://github.com/HenrikSchumacher/PardisoLink). So far, the package supports only matrices of real numbers.

I have to say that I am a really, really bad C++ programmer, so I give no guarantees for anything. *Use with caution.* I tested the package only on macos 10.15.4 with *Mathematica* 12.0 and the *clang* compiler and (only very briefly) with *Mathematica* 11.3 on Linux. I have absolutely no idea about Windows.

## Installation

I don't have any fancy installer, yet. Just download the package from github, unzip it, and drop it into the folder `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]`.

You might have to adjust the values of `"CompileOptions"` and `"LinkerOptions"` in the file `BuildSettings.m` in the package's base directory. You can get the appropriate values for your system by answering a couple of questions asked by this tool: `https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor/`.

If you find any problems, just contact me. Unfortunately, I do not have much time to maintain the package. Actually, my hope is that somebody at Wolfram Research will implement this feature in the near future. ;)

## Example

Okay, here is a simple usage example:

```
Needs["PardisoLink`"];
n = 1000000;
m = 20;
L = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -2. n, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1. n, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1. n}, {n, n}, 0.];
L[[1, 1]] = 1.;
L[[1, 2]] = 0.;
L[[-2, 1]] = 0.;
L[[n, n]] = 1.;
(*The following guarantees that L is CSR conform.*)
L = SparseArray[L];
b = ConstantArray[1./n, n];
B = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, m}];
b[[{-1, 1}]] = {0., 0.};
```

So, we have got a matrix and a couple of right hand sides. We can factorize the matrix with

```
P = Pardiso[L];
```

This results in a `Pardiso` object that is pretty much similar to `LinearSolveFunction` objects. But in constrast to almost everything in *Mathematica*, `Pardiso` is a **pointer type** with all its consequences. (In fact I have not implemented any deep copy routine for it. And it is almost impossible because the MKL Pardiso is pretty discrete about were it stores its data.) *So use with caution!*

You can solve a single equation with

```
x = P[b];
```

Or a couple of right hand sides contained in the matrix `B` by

```
X = P[B];
```

You can solve a linear system with the transpose of `L` with

```
y =P[b, "T"]
```

You can overwrite the stored matrix with another matrix with the same sparsity pattern as follows; this well keep the symbolic factorization:

```
P["Update"[-L]]
```

You will get an error message if you use that with a matrix that has not the same number of nonzero entries as the original matrix. However, for performance reasons, *the sparsity patterns are not compared*. *So use with caution!*

user21 has recently built in a way to use alternative linear solvers in `NDSolve`. Here is an example how you can use `Pardiso` for that:

```
ClearAll[x, y, u];
f = NDSolveValue[{
   Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    Sin[3 Pi x + 6 Pi y] + 2 Sin[7 Pi x + 5 Pi y] - 1,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]
   },
  u,
  {x, y} \[Element] Disk[],
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",
      "PDESolveOptions" -> {"LinearSolver" -> {Pardiso}}
      }
    }
  ]
```

It is not faster than `LinearSolve[#, Method ->"Pardiso"]` (it is the same backend!), but it should be able to provide quite a speed-up for for transient PDEs. In fact, the MKL Pardiso provides the feature to apply CG interations with the factorization as preconditioner (with automated refresh) for such a setup. I have not implemented it in `PardisoLink`, though. (And I am not going to do that in the near future, so don't ask ;) )

Per default, `Pardiso` performs something like an $LU$-decomposition (not really, but in the spirit). This corresponds to calling it with

```
P["Update"[L], "MatrixType"->11]
```

*In principle*, it should also support structurally symmetric matrices (not symmetric but with symmetric sparsity pattern, `"MatrixType"->1`), symmetric, but potentially indefinite matrices (`"MatrixType"->-2`), and symmetric, positive definite matrices (`"MatrixType"->2`). However, as I am writing this, I realize that the following throws an error. =O

```
n = 1000;
m = 20;
L = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -2. n, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1. n, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1. n}, {n, n}, 0.];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
P = Pardiso[L, "MatrixType" -> 2]
```

But `"MatrixType"->-2` seems to work. I have to see what I can do to fix that...

## Edit

Hah! Not a bug, but a feature: `Pardiso` told me that my assumption that the finite-difference Laplacian is positive-definite is actually wrong! It factorizes

```
P = Pardiso[-L, "MatrixType" -> 2]
```

without any problems.

Caution: `"MatrixType" -> 2` and `"MatrixType" -> -2` reads just the upper right triangle (including the diagonal) of the input matrix and neglects the lower left triangle (excluding the diagonal). Hence

```
Pardiso[-L, "MatrixType" -> 2]
```

and

```
Pardiso[-UpperTriangulize[L], "MatrixType" -> 2]
```

should have the same effect so that one can spare oneself the assembly of the lower left triangle.

## Tutorial

You can find a short tutorial here:

```
NotebookOpen@FileNameJoin[{PardisoLink`Private`$packageDirectory, "Documentation", "Examples", "Example.nb"}]
```

Comment: @Szabolcs Your "LTemplate`" package  at work. Would be great to have some feedback from you!

Comment: @Szabolcs Is there a way to return an empty vector `{}` (as `MTensor`)  from a LibraryLink function?

Comment: Just noting that we're not getting notifications from the @mentions unless we've participated in the discussion thread already. I found this by accident. I will definitely take a look tomorrow (it's late now).

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely return a 0-size vector. Do you want to return that as a matrix, is that the problem?

Comment: There are some functions that have to return the _vectors_ for the row pointers, columns indices, and nonzero values of the matrix. Everything is built so that you create a new `Pardiso` object with `Make`, but then the above data pointers just point to `NULL`. So the compiler complains that the functions that are meant to return these have no return value (I do not allow to return `NULL` because that crashes the WolframKernel). I think the best strategy would be to return `{}` then. Or is there a better idea?

Comment: @Szabolcs You may want to read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/284701

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah, something like `return mma::makeVector<mint>(0,ia)` indeed works like a charm when `ia` is a `NULL` pointer. (My former code said `return mma::makeVector<mreal>(n+1,ia)` which lead to an issue when `n=0` and `ia` was `NULL`.) Thanks for clarification!

Comment: This is really great @HenrikSchumacher! I think that there is a small mistake in the example file and in the implementation of "Update". After calling `P["Update"[-L]]` and computing `y=P[-b]` we should have `y==x`. The last line of the implementation of Update for SparseArrays reads `P["Update"[Developer\`ToPackedArray]]` and so it's not passing anything to the implementation of Update for Vector inputs (I fixed this by calling `P["Update"[A["NonzeroValues"]]]`). I think that in the Vector implementation it should be `a=Developer\`ToPackedArray[N[a0]]` instead of `ToPackedArrayQ`).

Comment: @beets You're so right! Thank you for pointing this out! I have updated the github version. I also improved the support for multiple right hand sides. See the example notebook in the packages' Documentation folder for details.